Proof of a continuity theorem for parameter-dependent integral functions
I try to prove the following theorem about the continuity of a parameter dependent integral function.
Thm. Let $(X,\mathcal{M})$ a measurable space, $\mu:\mathcal{M} \to [0,+\infty]$ a positive measure,  $(Y,\tau)$ a first countable topological space, $f:X\times Y \to [-\infty,+\infty]$ such that $f(\bullet, y)\in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu), \hspace{4pt} \forall y\in Y$.
Define $$\varphi:Y\to [-\infty, +\infty], \quad \varphi(y)=\int_X f(\bullet, y)\ d\mu$$
If $y_0\in Y$, if $f(x,\bullet)$ is continuous in $y_0$ for a.e. $x\in X$, if exists $U$ a neighborhood of $y_0$ in $Y$ and $\exists g\in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ such that $\forall y\in U, \hspace{4pt} |f(x,y)|\leq g(x), \hspace{4pt}$ for a.e. $x\in X$, then $\varphi$ is continuous at $y_0$.
Proof.
Since $(Y,\tau)$ is first countable, it is sufficient to show that $\varphi$ is continuous for sequences.
So, let $(y_j)_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence in $Y$ such that $y_j\overset{j}{\longrightarrow} y_0$.
Taking the neighborhood $U$ whose existence is assumed by hypothesis, by definition of convergent sequence, we have that there exists an index $j_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y_j\in U, \hspace{4pt} \forall j\geq j_0$. So, we can write that
$$\varphi(y_j)=\int_E f(\bullet,y_j)\ d\mu$$
where $E=\{x\in X \hspace{3pt} | \hspace{3pt} f(x,\bullet) \hspace{5pt}\mbox{is continuous in}\hspace{5pt} y_0\}$ and $\mu(X\setminus E)=0$.
In particular, $\forall y\in U$, it's true that $|f(x,y)|\leq g(x), \hspace{4pt} \forall x\in E$ and then $f(\bullet,y_j)\overset{j}{\longrightarrow} f(\bullet,y_0)$ a.e.
Therefore, we obtain that the hypotheses of the dominated convergence theorem are satisfied and therefore
$$\varphi(y_j)=\int_E f(\bullet,y_j)\ d\mu \overset{j}{\longrightarrow} \int_E f(\bullet,y_0) \ d\mu =\varphi(y_0)$$
$\Box$
Is my proof correct? I'm not sure about the application of dominated convergence theorem. Any help will be appreciated.
Can my proof be extended to vectorial functions?
